# error incompatible types when assigning to type from type in C

Tags: c

So I'm doing an assignment for school but I keep getting error messages, and I have read through multiple threads and I haven't found the soultion or maybe I'm just not understanding what's being said.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
//declare the variables
float radius, circumference;

radius = 0;

printf ("This program will calculate the circumference of a circle given the radius\n");

printf ("Please enter the radius of the circle:\n");
scanf ("%f", &radius);

circumference = calculate_circumference(radius);

printf ("The circumference of the circle is:\n", circumference);
return 0;
}

float calculate_circumferene (float circle_radius)
{

    float circle_circumference, PI;

    PI = 3.14159;

    circle_circumference = 2 * PI * circle_radius;

    return (circle_circumference);
}
```

Here are the error messages I'm getting:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:21:18: warning: implicit declaration of function  'calculate_circumference' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  circumference = calculate_circumference(radius);
              ^
prog.c:24:10: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
  printf ("The circumference of the circle is:\n", circumference);
      ^
/home/j1N8a0/ccUei3id.o: In function `main':
prog.c:(.text.startup+0x45): undefined reference to `calculate_circumference'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any type of help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare functions before using them and be careful for typo.

Though giving extra arguments to `printf()` is not harmful, but you have to use format specifier beginning with `%` to print data in variables via `printf()`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* declare the function to use */
float calculate_circumference (float circle_radius);

int main() {
    //declare the variables
    float radius, circumference;

    radius = 0;

    printf ("This program will calculate the circumference of a circle given the radius\n");

    printf ("Please enter the radius of the circle:\n");
    scanf ("%f", &radius);

    circumference = calculate_circumference(radius);

    /* add format specifier to print the value */
    printf ("The circumference of the circle is: %f\n", circumference);
    return 0;
}

/* add "c" before last "e" of the function name */
float calculate_circumference (float circle_radius)
{

    float circle_circumference, PI;

    PI = 3.14159;

    circle_circumference = 2 * PI * circle_radius;

    return (circle_circumference);
}
```